# mapbox-ios-sdk: setMinZoom of RMMapView

Tags: ios, mapbox

We can see the source code at [Github](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/blob/6bcf16ea02da9a6840d7da3097e52a71ba7a636b/MapView/Map/RMMapView.m#L2475-L2480).

What I thought is, these five line codes want to set the min zoom level to fit the uiview's bounds.

However, for an iPhone 5, the `boundingDimension` would be about `600`, and the `tileSideLength` here is `256`. so `boundingDimension / tileSideLength` is about `2.5`, and the `clampedMinZoom` would be equal to `1.xxx`. The result really doesn't make sense, right?

I really cannot understand these codes. Am I in the wrong way? Or maybe they did something wrong?